# Moment JS date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want to show / hide my table rows based on the day of week. The code I have at the moment shows / hides based on 24 hour time periods, rather than calendar days:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button type="button" id="button1">Monday</button>
<button type="button" id="button2">Tuesday</button>

<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Table</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

<tbody>
  <tr>        
   <td class="dates">13/02/2017 12:45 pm</td>       
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="dates">14/02/2017 12:45 pm</td>       
  </tr>

</tbody>


$('#button1').click(function(){
  var $dates = $('.dates');
  var m = moment().add(1, 'd');

$dates.each(function() {
  var date = moment($(this).text(), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a');
    if (date.isBetween(moment(), m)) {
      $(this).parent().show();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 'dddd' in moment.format() represents the day name of week you can easily compare it with button labels.

Attach the click handler to all buttons by adding a common class to them. jQuery allows selecting all elements that matches the selection criteria.

Once you get in the handler, take the clicked button's label and compare it to the parsed dates to decide show/hide each.

```js
$('.day-btns').click( function() {
  var btnText = $(this).text();
    $('.dates').each(function() {
    var date = moment($(this).text(), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a');
    if (date.format('dddd') == btnText) {
      $(this).parent().show();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="day-btns" id="button1">Monday</button>
<button type="button" class="day-btns" id="button2">Tuesday</button>

<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Table</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

<tbody>
  <tr>        
   <td class="dates">13/02/2017 12:45 pm</td>       
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="dates">14/02/2017 12:45 pm</td>       
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.weekday`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/) method to get a number based on the week day, you will get 0 for sunday, 1 for monday, etc..

> Gets or sets the day of the week according to the locale.

Example:

```
moment().weekday(); // code ran on a sunday
// 0
moment(new Date(1, 12, 2005)).weekday();
// 5
```

Note that the method is local aware, from the docs

> If the locale assigns Monday as the first day of the week, moment().weekday(0) will be Monday. If Sunday is the first day of the week, moment().weekday(0) will be Sunday.

Comment: Thank you I didnt know about this solution.